# How to change the z-index of chartjs annotations label?

Tags: javascript, annotations, chart.js

[Label is not overlapping the chart edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdUko.png)

Does anyone know if there is a way to set an z-index to make the label appears over the edge of the chart?

I am using the annotation plugin: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the annotation's clip property to false to ensure it appears outside of chart (see docs [here](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/samples/point/outsideChartArea.html)):

```
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 16
      }
    },
    scale: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        max: 100,
        min: 0
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        clip: false,
        common: {
          drawTime: 'afterDraw'
        },
        annotations: {
          annotation1,
          annotation2
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set drawTime on "beforeDraw".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please improvise your comments by giving code snippets